# Is there a way to work with sources from different databases in tableau

Tags: mysql, postgresql, tableau-desktop, cross-database

I have 2 separate tables in Postgre and MySQL. They have 2 common fields but I can't join them because there are no option to make full outer join.

I've tried to add them seperately but I can't do it. Tableau allows me only to join them.

Comment: [mysql_fdw](https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/mysql_fdw).

Comment: clarify your question with details such as table structure if you want helpful replies

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes It is possible, you just need to add 2 separate connections under the same data source in Tableau